# Why doesn't this work to convert a list of map to a single map?

Tags: python

convert a list of map to a single map?

```
label_name_mapping = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3}]
label_name_mapping = {k: v for k, v in (x.items() for x in label_name_mapping)}
```

I want to get a single map:

```
 label_name_mapping = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't iterate enough.

Both `for`s are on the same level of items in your main list. You have to nest the loops:

```
{k:v for x in label_name_mapping for k, v in x.items()}
```

Comment: She did try to nest them, she just did it in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Good point on iteration mentioned above. You can also try the built in update method for maps:

```
master_map = {}

for map in label_name_mapping:
    master_map.update(map)

{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```